# MongoDb, prevent from creating same object two times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket

The thing I had to do was to create database with MongoDb, Node.js and connect with WebSocket server, and keep updating database with data sent from Websockets. Websockets sends many kind of data connected to particular id of device. Works fine, connection is established, it keeps updating Mongo but the thing is that sometimes when data about particular device is sent first time, it creates same object twice. Not sure If I explained correctly what I mean, but idea is to not let Mongo double device while creating it.

```
connection.onmessage = e => {
    const resp = JSON.parse(e.data)
    const server_name = e.target._socket._host.slice(0, 5)
    setTimeout(() => {
        push_data_to_database(resp, server_name)
    },500)
```

}

```
push_data_to_database = (message, server) => {
    // console.log("data::::", message)
    deviceControllers.addDevice({device_id: message.device_id, server_name: server})

    if (message.event == 'SCRIPT_START') {
        deviceControllers.updateDevice(
            {device_id: message.device_id},
            {scriptexecute_timestamp: message.timestamp}
        )
    } 
}
```

And Function to add device to database

```
exports.addDevice = async(req, resp) => {
    try {
        const validation = await Device.find(req)
        if (!validation.length && req.device_id !== undefined) {
            const device = new Device(req)
            console.log('added:',device)
            return device.save()
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique index for that "device_id" in the collection so that the second entry addition will give error. This unique index ensures there is no duplicate values for the indexed field.

db.collection_name.createIndex({"device_id": 1}, {"unique": true})

You can also create unique index combining multiple fields.

Comment: when i try to create index it gives error that "Device.index is not a function "
`const device = Device.index({device_id: req.device_id}, {unique: true})`

Comment: oki doki I solved it by specifying in scheme that _id should have id of device_id and now everything seems to work fine:) Thanks for hint with this index!